# How to change the value with all specific key in the nested state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to find all the state value with key `style` and change the value with `red` in my nested state following below.

```
this.state = {
  front: {
    line1: {
      style: "blue",
      name: "name1"
    },
    line2: {
      style: "blue",
      name: "name2"
    }
  }
}
```

I have done a try like following, but it gives error.

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach(function(k,prevState) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ [k]:
        {...prevState[k], style: "red"} 
  }))
});
```

How can I update it?

Comment: `but it gives error` what error?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: The second prameter of the forEach callback shouldn't be prevState. Its the index of the key in the array generated by Object.keys(this.state)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on the `front` object to get an array with all the key names, and then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on that and build up a new `front` object where you change all the `style` properties to `"red"`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    front: {
      line1: {
        style: "blue",
        name: "name1"
      },
      line2: {
        style: "blue",
        name: "name2"
      }
    }
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(({ front }) => ({
      front: Object.keys(front).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = {
          ...front[key],
          style: "red"
        };
        return acc;
      }, {})
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Change to red</button>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Could you update the code to get the result for the current nested state. Kindly check the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @Hareesh It's generally not a good practice to rewrite your question when you have gotten answers. Do you just want to check the `state.front`, or any nested object in your state?

Comment: Just want to check under state.front

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tholle

Answer (score 0):

You have proplem because you not use arrow function. You should use array function to have access to `setState`

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach((k,prevState) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ [k]:
        {...prevState[k], style: "red"} 
  }))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a copy of state and than loop through it and change the values of style key and update state

```
let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
Object.keys(copy).forEach(e=>{
  copy[key].style = 'red'
})
this.setState(copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurred because you used ES5 function in your forEach callback meaning that the callback has a function scope, where `this` refers to the callback function's context.

Solution 1: Use ES6 arrow function. Arrow functions have the scope of where it's defined.

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach((k) => {
   this.setState({ [k]: {...this.state[k], style: 'red' }})
});
```

Solution 2: Use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value.

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach(function(k) {
   this.setState({ [k]: {...this.state[k], style: 'red' }})
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it -specifically: how does this change the `style` value for all items where this value is present?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a method to set red styles in the state.
You can copy and paste the code below and edit it to your liking.

```
setRedStyles = () => {
  const newState = { ...this.state };
  Object.keys(newState.front).forEach(prop => {
    if (newState.front[prop].style) {
      newState.front[prop].style = "red";
    }
    this.setState(newState);
  });
}
```

You should be able to call setRedStyles() in your onClick function on call this function directly.